# Apply MIN() OVER only on percentage of the rows

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions, analytic-functions

I have the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM empno,
     ename,
     deptno,
     sal,
     job,
     MIN(sal) OVER (PARTITION BY deptno, job) AS min_sal_by_dept_and_job
FROM emp;
```

With this result:
[Query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfSB5.png)

I want the column min_sal_by_dept_and_job to exclude X percent of the sal column. Let's say 50%
so in this case the first two rows with sal 1250 and 1250 will be excluded and min_sal_by_dept_and_job will no longer be 1250 but 1500 because it is the min from 1500 and 1600. Simply said, I want the min() to be applied only on certain percentage of the rows.

Comment: How do you compute that 50% that you mention?

Comment: as far as I understand from your explanations in `min_sal_by_dept_and_job` column 
 should be inserted second min value. Is that true?

Comment: Currently `min_sal_by_dept_and_job` shows the minimum of 1250, 1250, 1500, 1600 which is 1250 for each row. I need to exclude the first 50 percent of the rows in the calculation. In this case since we have 4 rows, I need to exclude the first two, so that the `MIN()` will be applied on the second two rows - the minimum of 1500 and 1600. As a result `min_sal_by_dept_and_job` should be 1500 for each row.

Comment: @AleixCC it is fixed. It is percentage of rows. I gave it as 50% because it is easier. The actual business requirement is to exclude 5% of the lowest salaries in the calculation.

Comment: Ok, so it could be based on percentiles then, right? All salaries lower (and including) the 5th percentile should not be counted in the calculation?

Comment: Yes, exactly right

Answer (score 1):

According to your explanations above you can try this one:

```
SELECT e.empno, ename, deptno, sal, job, 
       MIN(SAL) OVER (PARTITION BY deptno, job) AS min_sal_by_dept_and_job 
 FROM (SELECT empno, ename, deptno, sal, job,
              count(*) over () as cnt_rows,
              row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY deptno, job ORDER BY sal DESC) AS ROW_num
         FROM emp) e 
WHERE ROW_NUM <=0.5*cnt_rows
GROUP BY empno, ename, deptno, sal, job;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it returns exactly the same. From the example above: `min_sal_by_dept_and_job` is the same(1250) for `DEPTNO = 30' and `JOB = SALESMAN` where it should be 1500

Comment: It looks like there are more than 4 records for `DEPTNO = 30` and `JOB = SALESMAN` and the count of populated value `SAL = 1250` is more than 2 rows, i.e. is it possible in the second 50 percent ( the included rows in your report) there is a value 1250 -> if - yes => the records will be included in your report.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are not. There are 14 rows in total and only 4 for `DEPTNO = 30` and `JOB = SALESMAN` The demo setup can be taken from here: [Demo setup](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/min-and-max-analytic-functions)